# Remote password generation

Tags: c#, password-recovery

We have a system deployed in remote locations where internet access isn't guaranteed, a part of the system requires a password, however users may forget their password and ask for recovery options.

I'm trying to create a tool which would allow me to generate recovery passwords, the passwords will need to be unique to a system (the systems can provide a unique numeric identifier) and time sensitive.

Ideally, the system will work this way: User calls support and provides his system identifier. Support inputs his identifier in the recovery tool and get back a password that is valid during this hour/day. When the user inputs the generated password back in his system, the system would allow access.

I suppose the remote system will have to generate the password in the same method, to compare with the password provided by support, which may provide a security risk, some reverse-engineering proofing would be needed for the code.
I'm looking for a C# solution but other methods are welcome.

Comment: yuck. i wouldn't do this. are the machines bound to an active directory domain?

Comment: @Daniel I agree with you on the yuck aspect, but it's beyond my control, there is a system currently implemented which is worse and even more unsecure.  
I cannot assume any form of authentication is present on the remote machine, the only security I know is present is the one implemented into our system.

Answer (score 1):

Create a form that is shipped with the product that creates a machine specific Hash, which the user reads to the tech support agent over the phone. The agent then enters the Hash into a form that is available only to your support agents. This form takes the hash and a salt value, and returns a new Hash, which is read back to the user. The user then enters this new Hash which brings up a reset password form.

The function that creates the new Hash on the agents end would have to be implemented on the client side also for validation. I'd suggest just simply adding a static salt to the machine specific hash.